# Google analytics with fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, google-analytics

I am using fragments in my app. Every fragment takes the whole screen. Is there any way to do `EasyTracker.getInstance().activityStart(activity);` to a fragment?
I need to do that so I can see the "Avg. Time on Screen" of each of the fragments. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In your Fragment:

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    EasyTracker tracker = EasyTracker.getInstance(getActivity());
    tracker.set(Fields.SCREEN_NAME, "Screen Name");
    tracker.send(MapBuilder.createAppView().build());
}
```

Reference:

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v2/screens#manual
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v3/migration#v2

Comment: When I try this, I see nothing in Google Analytics indicating what fragment was visited...

Comment: @Ted have you put the code to your fragment? Have changed `"Screen Name"` to the name of your fragment?

Comment: yes. It works, but you don't see it in "Real-time", it only shows up some 24 hours later...

Answer (score 1):

Even if you are using Fragments , you must be having a parent Activity to which your Fragment attaches, use this code `EasyTracker.getInstance().activityStart(activity);`in the onStart method of that Fragment Activity.

Comment: But I have a lot of fragments in one activity, So this way it will only set the activity time and not each of the fragments time...